# DSpace loginAs does not work

Tags: authentication, dspace

In dspace.cfg in DPspace 5.3 I set webui.user.assumelogin = true to be able to login as another person during tests.

I log in as an Adminstrator. 
In the JSPUI Admistrator screen I don't see the 'Login As' button at all. Under XMLUI the 'Login as E-Person' button is present, but colored grey, so I cannot click on it.

What can be the cause of this behavoir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure to restart the server after changing the configuration to make sure your changes are applied.

Comment: I sure restarted tomcat7, Philip. But I still could not and can not login as another person.

Comment: After restarting the whole (Ubuntu) server, and restarting Tomcat, I could login as another person.
But after the server-restart DSpace is not working smoothly, so there is more work to do. I guess irregularities in the database

Answer (score 0):

You cannot log in as another administrator -- that's probably why the button is greyed out in XMLUI. It may also be the reason for the button not appearing at all in JSPUI.

Comment: I know, Schweerelos. After a complete restart of the server (see my comment to Philip V's answer) I could login as another (non-adminstrator) user.